# Model.findOne() function not working when passed a variable as the value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js.
I am trying to create function, where a randomly generated String is queried to check if it exists or not. If it already exists, the String is randomly generated till it is unique.

```
      let validID = false;
      console.log(temp); //temp is the randomly generated String.
      while(!validID){
        Website.findOne({shortcut: temp},function(err,docs){
            if(docs==null){
              validID = true;
              console.log("The shortcut for the url is" + temp);              
            }else{
              console.log("FOUND");
              temp = generateId();
            }
        });
      }
```

When run, the code is stuck in an infinite while loop.

I tried to see whether the code works with a String value ( not a variable ) passed in as the query inside findOne(). It worked. I am assuming that the fact that temp is a variable is causing the problem. Can variables be passed in as a value in a query? If so, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Website.findOne` operates asynchronously, i.e. the `callback`-function you passed to it, will be run once the results from the mongodb are fetched. However, node will not be able to actually process this callback, since your callstack never gets emptied due to your `while`-loop. If you're interested, you can find out more about this [here](https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop).

One way to solve this is to wrap your Mongo-DB call in a promise, wait for it to resolve, then return if the ID is unique and continue by calling it recursively otherwise (note that this can be highly simplified by using `async/await` but for understanding how this works using `promised` are beneficial imo):

```
function findIdPromise(temp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Website.findOne({
            shortcut: temp
        }, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(docs);    
        });
    });
}

function getNextIsUniqueIdPromise(shortcut) {
    return findIdPromise()
    .then(docs => {
        if (docs == null) {
            return shortcut;
        }
        return getNextIsUniqueIdPromise(generateId());    
    });

}

// call it initially with
getNextIsUniqueIdPromise(firstShortcutToCheck)
.then(shortcut => {
 console.log("The shortcut for the url is" + shortcut):
})
.catch(err => {
console.log("an error occured", err):
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I'll try to use async/await as you suggested too!